# no instance of overloaded function "AfxBeginThread" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

am trying to make a worker thread using MFC so here is the codes:

```
struct ThreadParam
{
    HWND mDlg;    // Note: A handle.
};

UINT TestMFCThread::Test( LPVOID pParam ){
  //do work!
}
void TestMFCThread::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    ThreadParam* param = new ThreadParam;
    param->mDlg = m_hWnd;
    AfxBeginThread(Test, param);
}
```

but it gives me this error :

```
1   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "AfxBeginThread" matches the argument list
    argument types are: (UINT (LPVOID pParam), ThreadParam *)
```

idk whats wrong it's supposed to be right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [AfxBeginThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you need to cast the second argument to `LPVOID`:

```
AfxBeginThread(Test, (LPVOID) param);
```

and set calling convention of `Test` to `__cdecl`:

```
UINT __cdecl Test( LPVOID lParam)
```

Comment: I tried that and it's still giving me errors `1 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "AfxBeginThread" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (UINT (LPVOID pParam), LPVOID)`

Comment: Updated answer regarding calling convention.

Comment: even after adding `__cdecl` it still gives me arguments error `1 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "AfxBeginThread" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (UINT __cdecl (LPVOID pParam), LPVOID)`

Comment: @MixedCoder: Is `Test` a method inside a class?

Comment: Move it outside of `TestMFCThread` class or declare it `static`.

Answer (score -1):

just declare your member function as static , it will solve the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).